# Cannot creat UTM tags due to server error for GA tracking

Tags: google-analytics

I am unable to create UTM tags do to the error "No OAuth client ID available. Make sure to attach it as a global in the server! This is a developer error, not a user error."

Any advice would be fab. Thanks

Ps. novice here so I hope this isn't a very naive question!

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that this is a problem at Google's end. They have made a mistake configuring their link shortening application. It's not your fault and there's nothing you can do to fix it.

Comment: Thanks - I had initially thought that but after a colleague who has more experience with the platform was unsure I thought to check. The response is appreciated.